# 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to System.Collections.Generic.List<string>[*,*]

Tags: c#, arraylist

I am using C# asp.net in my project. I use 2d array in that. Named roomno. When I try to remove one row in that. So I Convert the array into list.

```
static string[,] roomno = new string[100, 14];
List<string>[,] lst = new List<string>[100, 14];



lst = roomno.Cast<string>[,]().ToList();

Error   1   Invalid expression term 'string' in this line...
if i try below code,
 lst = roomno.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

I got

```
Error   3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>[*,*]'
```

> lst = roomno.Cast().ToList();

What is the Mistake in my code?.

After that, I plan to remove the row in list, `lst.RemoveAt(array_qty);`

Comment: I'm not sure if converting 2d array of string to 2d array of list makes sense. Why did you decide to do so?

Comment: I try use list.removeat() in my program. Is any better way to remove roomno[0,0] to roomno[0,14] in array.

Comment: The mistake in your code seems to be that you're trying to make a 2-dimensional list of strings, analogous to your 2-dimensional array of strings.  This is a mistake because the generic `List<>` type does not support multiple dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
List<string>[,] lst = new List<string>[100, 14];
```

is declaring a 2-D array of `List<string>` values.

This:

```
roomno.Cast<string>[,]().ToList();
```

... simply doesn't make sense due to the position of the `[,]` between the type argument and the `()` for the method invocation. If you changed it to:

```
roomno.Cast<string[,]>().ToList();
```

then it would be creating a `List<string[,]>` but it's still not the same as a `List<string>[,]`.

Additionally, `roomno` is just a 2-D array of strings - which is actually a single sequence of strings as far as LINQ is concerned - so why are you trying to convert it into an essentially *3*-dimensional type?

It's not clear what you're trying to do or why you're trying to do it, but hopefully this at least helps to explain why it's not working...

To be honest, I would try to avoid mixing 2-D arrays and lists within the same type. Would having another custom type help?

EDIT: LINQ isn't going to be much use with a 2-D array. It's designed for single sequences really. I suspect you'll need to do it "manually" - here's a short but complete program as an example:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)        
    {
        string[,] values = {
            {"x", "y", "z"},
            {"a", "b", "c"},
            {"0", "1", "2"}
        };

        values = RemoveRow(values, 1);

        for (int row = 0; row < values.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < values.GetLength(1); column++)
            {
                Console.Write(values[row, column]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    private static string[,] RemoveRow(string[,] array, int row)
    {
        int rowCount = array.GetLength(0);
        int columnCount = array.GetLength(1);
        string[,] ret = new string[rowCount - 1, columnCount];

        Array.Copy(array, 0, ret, 0, row * columnCount);
        Array.Copy(array, (row + 1) * columnCount,
                   ret, row * columnCount, (rowCount - row - 1) * columnCount);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried lst = roomno.Cast<string>().ToList(); also But Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>[*,*]' Error is come.

Comment: I try to remove one row in my 2d array. Is any Simple way is there?.

Comment: @Sagotharan: It's not clear what you're even trying to do though. Please clarify that in your question instead of just trying different bits of syntax until something compiles. Coding shouldn't be a "try it and see" exercise.

Comment: @Sagotharan: Your array doesn't really have "rows" - have you considered using a `string[][]` instead? Or a `List<List<string>>`? Again, if you could provide more context that would really help.

Comment: Please help me to remove a one row in my 2d array. That's enough.

Comment: @Sagotharan: See my edit. Basically using LINQ isn't a good fit here.

Comment: Thanks Alot. Now it remove array row

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use 2-dimensional List, try `List<List<string>>()`. But conversation to array in that case could be: `list.Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToArray()` and that is `string[][]` but not `string[,]`